# Free Windows application to convert SWF to WAV?

Tags: swf, wav

Is there a free application for Windows to extract the sound from an SWF file into WAV?

I tried opening the file in VLC 1.1.11, but it just crashed, and 2.0 is pretty recent so I'd rather wait.

Thank you.

Comment: "*and 2.0 is pretty recent so I'd rather wait*" If it solves your problem, why?

Comment: Because I have no assurance it will solve the issue and time is not free :-)

Comment: Tried the portable 2.0.1: "VLC can't recognize the input's format: The format of 'file:///myfile.swf' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Vixy](http://vixy.net/) to record and convert it straight off the net, if you remember where you got that flash file from.

You could try [AoA Audio Extractor](http://majorgeeks.com/AoA_Audio_Extractor_d5496.html) as it is made to rip audio from FLV (Flash Video) files.

You could install [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and then just use it to record the audio output of your computer, as you play the SWF file from the net.

As to the SWF file crashing when you play it with VLC... well, it could be crashing to the file being corrupt.  Go back to the source and start again.

Comment: Thanks, but AoA failed extracting sound from the SWF file, which plays OK when drag 'n dropped onto Chrome.

Comment: Problem solved by setting Audacity in recording mode, playing the URL in a browser, and exporting data as WAV. Thanks for the tip.